# How do I create this xml with PHP's SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap

From debugging another application, I found that it sends the following xml to a soap server (code parts in this example are minimized, the xml is about 200 lines long:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:m0="http://schemas.ccs.nl/datacatalogus/modellen/modelrelatie">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <m:header xmlns:m="http://schemas.ccs.nl/soap">
        <m:account>account</m:account>
        <m:naam>naam_header</m:naam>
        <m:wachtwoord>wachtwoord</m:wachtwoord>
        <m:bedrijfsnummer>bedrijfsnummer</m:bedrijfsnummer>
        <m:tussenpersoonnummer>tussenpersoonnummer</m:tussenpersoonnummer>
    </m:header>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <m:RelatieMuteren xmlns:m="http://schemas.ccs.nl/services/relatieservice">
        <m:relatie pc="W">
            <m0:adres>adres</m0:adres>
        </m:relatie>
    </m:RelatieMuteren>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Obviously, the part between `<m0:adres></m0:adres>` is a lot larger and corresponds to my data that is stored in an array. However, if I try to send the request using `__soapCall`, PHP builds the following request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.ccs.nl/datacatalogus/modellen/modelrelatie"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.ccs.nl/services/relatieservice" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.ccs.nl/soap">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns3:header>
            <ns3:account>account</ns3:account>
            <ns3:naam>naam</ns3:naam>
            <ns3:wachtwoord>wachtwoord</ns3:wachtwoord>
            <ns3:bedrijfsnummer>bedrijfsnummer</ns3:bedrijfsnummer>
            <ns3:tussenpersoonnummer>tussenpersoonnummer</ns3:tussenpersoonnummer>
        </ns3:header>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:RelatieMuteren>
            <ns2:relatie pc="I">
                <ns1:adres>Postbus 53</ns1:adres>
            </ns2:relatie>
        </ns2:RelatieMuteren>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As you can see, the second xml is quite different from the first. Can anyone explain me why it is different and how I can create the first type of xml?

I use the following code to do the request:

```
$client = new SoapClient( "http://www.cdsverzekeringen.nl/ws_prod/services/RelatieService.asmx?WSDL", array( 'trace' => 1 ) );
$aHeader =  array(
    'account' => "PRIVATE", 
    'naam' => "PRIVATE",
    'wachtwoord' => "PRIVATE",
    'bedrijfsnummer' => "PRIVATE",
    'tussenpersoonnummer' => "PRIVATE",
);
$client->__setSoapHeaders( new SoapHeader( "http://schemas.ccs.nl/soap", 'header', $aHeader ) );
$vtResult = $client->__soapCall( "RelatieMuteren", array( $aRelatieInfo ) );
```

The $aRelatieInfo array is formatted like this:

```
array
  'relatie' => 
    array
      'adres' => string 'Postbus 53' (length=10)
```

I hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well the XML certainly look different but they really aren't. If you "resolve" the namespaces in your head (or on a piece of paper/in a text-editor) you see, that the schema of both XML-documents is equal. If the service is not giving you the expected results, please tell us what result you are expecting and what the service currently returns (if there's an error message please paste the full error-message)

Comment: That's the problem.. it simply returns a client code which should mean the data is processed. However, it isn't changed, so I figured my xml was wrong.

Comment: Well the only difference I see is that the `pc`attribute of the `relatie` structure is "I" instead of "W". If you set the `pc` to `"W"` the requests should be equivalent. Have you tried adding `$aRelatieInfo['relatie']['pc'] = "W";`?

Answer (score 0):

How about using SoabVar API like this,

```
$aHeader = '
<m:header xmlns:m="http://schemas.ccs.nl/soap">
    <m:account>account</m:account>
    <m:naam>naam_header</m:naam>
    <m:wachtwoord>wachtwoord</m:wachtwoord>
    <m:bedrijfsnummer>bedrijfsnummer</m:bedrijfsnummer>
    <m:tussenpersoonnummer>tussenpersoonnummer</m:tussenpersoonnummer>
</m:header>';
$soap_var_header = new SoapVar( $aHeader , XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null);

$client->__setSoapHeaders( new SoapHeader( "http://schemas.ccs.nl/soap", 'm', $soap_var_header ) );
```